# mysql "where" without using "from"

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this valid syntax? It seems like the `from` clause should be implied when explicitly naming the table and column, `table.column`.

```
SELECT
       distinct concat(\"Question \", q.place) as question
  FROM q
       INNER JOIN test
             ON test.id = q.test
             AND q.id NOT IN (
                 SELECT responses.question 
               where   //Is this Valid or do I need to select from a table explicitly?
                        responses.tester = tester.id)
       INNER JOIN test
             ON test.id = testingsession.test
       INNER JOIN tester
             ON tester.test = test.id
 WHERE 
       tester.id = :id
ORDER BY
       questions.position
```

Comment: Well, does it work or yield an error?

Comment: What's the problem with specifying a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL it's valid to have a `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause, but that returns singleton row (similar to using the special DUAL table from Oracle) and you can't use a `WHERE` clause.

In your case, the SELECT query is returning values from a table, so you need a `FROM` clause to reference that table.

To answer your question, no, what you have is not valid.

---

**NOTES:**

For performance, I'd use an anti-join pattern over a `NOT IN (correlated_subquery)`.

There's several problems in the syntax:

You've got the `test` table referenced twice. At least one of those references is going to be assigned an alias.

You've got a reference to `testingsession.test`, but there is no `testingsession` row source in your query.

The query references `questions.positions` in the `ORDER BY` clause, but there is no `questions` row source.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Is there a reason why this is so? It seems like this would be pretty intuitive way of selecting rows from a table.

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty I think the answer is in your comment, "selecting rows from a table".  Without `FROM` there's no table from which to select.

Answer (score 3):

That is not valid! You cannot use a column from a table that is not included in your `FROM / JOIN` part (here `responses.tester`). You will have to join `responses` too.